# MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY default directory

Tags: directory, default, nsis

I am building an NSIS installer. I would like the user to specify two different directories. I am using two MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY pages like so:

```
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_VARIABLE $SomeDir
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_DESTINATION "Some directory"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
```

I would like the first page to come up with a default directory for `SomeDir`. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Function .onInit
StrCpy $SomeDir "$AppData\MyDefault"
FunctionEnd
```